Understanding the role of `shuffle` in np.random.Generator.choice()
From the documentation for numpy's random.Generator.choice function, one of the arguments is shuffle, which defaults to True.
The documentation states:

shuffle  bool, optional
Whether the sample is shuffled when sampling without replacement. Default is True, False provides a speedup.

There isn't enough information for me to figure out what this means.  I don't understand why we would shuffle if it's already appropriately random, and I don't understand why I would be given the option to not shuffle if that yields a biased sample.
If I set shuffle to False am I still getting a random (independent) sample?   I'd love to also understand why I would ever want the default setting of True.

You are still getting a random choice regardless of your selection for shuffle. If you select shuffle=False, however, the ordering of the output is not independent of the ordering of the input.
This is easiest to see when the number of items chosen equals the total number of items:
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = np.arange(10)
rng.choice(x, 10, replace=False, shuffle=False)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
rng.choice(x, 10, replace=False, shuffle=True)
# array([8, 1, 3, 9, 6, 5, 0, 7, 4, 2])

If you reduce the number of items chosen and use shuffle=False, you can confirm that which item(s) are missing is distributed as expected.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = np.arange(10)
set_x = set(x)
missing = []
for i in range(10000):
    # By default, all `p` are equal, so which item is
    # missing should be uniformly distributed
    y = rng.choice(x, 9, replace=False, shuffle=False)
    set_y = set(y)
    missing.append(set_x.difference(set_y).pop())
plt.hist(missing)


But you'll see that items that appeared earlier in x tend to appear earlier in the output and vice-versa. That is, the input and output orders are correlated.
x = np.arange(10)
correlations = []
for i in range(10000):
    y = rng.choice(x, 9, replace=False, shuffle=False)
    correlations.append(stats.spearmanr(np.arange(9), y).statistic)
plt.hist(correlations)


If that is ok for your application, feel free to set shuffle=False for a speedup.
%timeit rng.choice(10000, 5000, replace=False, shuffle=True)
# 187 µs ± 26.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit rng.choice(10000, 5000, replace=False, shuffle=False)
# 146 µs ± 18.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

The more items that are to be chosen, the more pronounced the speedup.
%timeit rng.choice(10000, 1, replace=False, shuffle=True)
# 17.6 µs ± 3.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit rng.choice(10000, 1, replace=False, shuffle=False)
# 16.5 µs ± 2.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

vs
%timeit rng.choice(10000, 9999, replace=False, shuffle=True)
# 214 µs ± 32.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit rng.choice(10000, 9999, replace=False, shuffle=False)
# 124 µs ± 27.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


As @matt-haberland has already presented the statistics, randomness is unaffected by the presence or absence of shuffling.
However, in fact, the elements chosen are the same. The assert statement in the code below will not fail.
import numpy as np

n = 1000
m = 100

for seed in range(1000):
    result_with_shuffle = np.random.default_rng(seed).choice(range(n), size=m, replace=False, shuffle=True)
    result_without_shuffle = np.random.default_rng(seed).choice(range(n), size=m, replace=False, shuffle=False)
    assert list(result_with_shuffle) != list(result_without_shuffle)
    assert set(result_with_shuffle) == set(result_without_shuffle)

Also, as mentioned by @matt-haberland, the easiest way to see that the ordering of the output is (or is not) independent of the ordering of the input is to sample the same number of elements as the input, but you should be aware that some trends will appear even with much smaller sizes.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 10000
m = 2000
seed = 0

sample_with_shuffle = np.random.default_rng(seed).choice(range(n), size=m, replace=False, shuffle=True)
sample_without_shuffle = np.random.default_rng(seed).choice(range(n), size=m, replace=False, shuffle=False)


def plot(sample, title, index):
    plt.subplot(1, 2, index)
    plt.bar(range(m), sample)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("Index")
    plt.ylabel("Value")


plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))
plot(sample_with_shuffle, "shuffle=True", 1)
plot(sample_without_shuffle, "shuffle=False", 2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Although the sample without shuffling appears random when we look at the first couple of values, but the graph clearly reveals an upward trend from left to right.
In summary, if the ordering of the outputs matters, you should always shuffle. Otherwise, there is no advantage.
